# 'lightercollective' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, package.json

I have installed webpack now I am trying to install webpack-cli but following errors occur:

```
    $ npm i --save-dev webpack-cli

    > webpack-cli@3.2.1 postinstall D:\Development\Practices\sample\starter\node_modules\webpack-cli
    > lightercollective

    'lightercollective' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
    operable program or batch file.
    npm WARN starter@1.0.0 No description
    npm WARN starter@1.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! webpack-cli@3.2.1 postinstall: `lightercollective`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-cli@3.2.1 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-08T08_45_44_898Z-debug.log
```

**Notes:**

- I have tried restarting my command line.
- I have also tried `npm cache clean --force`
- And googling about an hour.
- Finally, what does that **lightercollective is not recognized as..** in the above message means? Confused???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install:

npm i -g lightercollective

They change stuff... you must specify version numbers when you get packages or it won't work in the future if there is some sort of a breaking change.

Comment: This is a workaround. Unfortunately, there seems to be an issue with how npm resolves scripts in some environments. Installing lightercollective globally will get around this issue for now, but if you install another library which has a dependency on opencollective, you will find yourself back in the same situation. Until this gets sorted, I believe library authors should be urged to append "|| exit 0" to their postinstall to ensure it doesn't bomb out critical processes downstream.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `lightercollective` to your dependencies to solve the issue.

[Official package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightercollective)

`"lightercollective": "^0.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Update webpack-cli: `npm update webpack-cli --save-dev`

In my situation, I went from 3.2.1 (which warned about "lightercollective") to 3.3.8. Seemed like the issue was resolved.